# How can I connect to a database?

Tags: 7, database

So I'm new to Drupal and am creating my first module. I can get the page to display html, but I'm not quite sure how to connect to the MySQL database. Here is my code:

```
<?php
// $Id$

/**
 * @News
 * First module
 *
 * Just a simple news module
 */

function news_main() {
    db_set_active('default');
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news");
    while ($news = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
        $output .= '<h1>'.$news->title.'</h1><p>'.$news->body.'</p><p>'.$news->date.'</p>';
    }
    return $output;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function news_menu() {
    $items = array();

    $items['news'] = array(
        'page callback' => 'news_main',
        'title' => 'News',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
     );

    return $items;
}
?>
```

I just get a blank page whenever I try to view it. I'm sure it's something simple, but I'm completely new to Drupal and it's API. I've looked through documentation for hours and couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what's happening is you're querying a database that you're not connected to.

```
db_set_active('default');
```

...that makes the active database the Drupal default (the one it was installed on, usually).

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news");
```

...that doesn't actually do anything.  That is a MySQL Library function (i.e. not part of the Drupal API), so Drupal doesn't actually interact with it.

Now, depending on what you're trying to do here, it's not clear if you're trying to query a table that's part of the Drupal installation or if it's a secondary, external table in a database you're trying to connect to... however, based on the logic you're using I'm going to assume the table is in the Drupal database.

If news is a table in the default Drupal database, then what you want to use is `db_query`, and the API information for it is located here https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7.  You can read about interacting with the Drupal database through the Drupal API there.

Here's an example I pulled from the Migrate module:

```
$query = db_select('migrate_example_beer_topic', 'met')
         ->fields('met', array('style', 'details', 'style_parent', 'region','hoppiness'))
         // This sort assures that parents are saved before children.
         ->orderBy('style_parent', 'ASC');
```

Notice you don't actually have to specify the database you're connecting to, it just assumed 'default'.

In fact, for that matter, you should install the Migrate module and go through the examples that it has.  They come with the module, and will be accessible under sites/all/modules/migrate/migrate_example.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the accepted answer, you don't use directly plain PHP functions to access the database, in Drupal. They don't have access to the database information Drupal uses; as such, your call to `db_set_active()` doesn't influence them.

Since by default Drupal uses the database defined in settings.php as `$databases['default']['default']`, your call to `db_set_active()` is perfectly useless: Just use the database function Drupal has, and you are all set.

If we are talking about accessing a database Drupal doesn't have set as default, then you need to use code similar to the following. I don't use `db_set_active()` simply for the fact it changes the database used from other modules, which could cause them to fail.

```
// db_select()
$query = Database::getConnection($target)->select($table, $alias, $options);

// db_insert()
$query = Database::getConnection($target)->insert($table, $options);

// db_delete()
$query = Database::getConnection($target)->delete($table, $options);
```

If the settings.php file doesn't contain the definition for the database you want to access, you can add it to the definition Drupal knows.

```
Database::addConnectionInfo($key, $target, $info);
```

`$info` is an array as described in [default.settings.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/sites%21default%21default.settings.php/7). For example, to access a SQLite database, it is similar to the following.

```
$info = array(
  'driver' => 'sqlite',
  'database' => '/path/to/databasefilename',
);
```

There is no need to first check the information is already know to Drupal, since Drupal doesn't add the same information twice. If your module is using a specific connection, be sure to use for `$key` a value that doesn't conflict with any value used from Drupal or third-party modules. (It is enough to prefix its value with the short name of the module.)